# Emacs: How do I stop my Python process from being killed by Ctrl-C

Tags: python, linux, emacs, ipython

Using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), running Emacs 24.5.1, Python 3.5.2, and IPython 5.1.0.  I often work with `python-mode`, with a live IPython prompt running in a buffer.  I commonly run a function or loop, and sometimes need to break it early to examine stuff, usually while exploring data.

However, the first time I press Ctrl-C, this works fine, and the IPython process goes back to its prompt.  Unfortunately the second time I press Ctrl-C, invariably the process exits with the message,

```
Process Python[myscript.py] interrupt
```

Then if I `C-c C-c` again, a new IPython process is started in the same buffer.  However, my process is dead and I can't examine the variables and have to re-run it from the beginning.  This is very annoying!  I've searched but can't figure out why it only happens the *second* time I press Ctrl-C.

One possibility is that the process is receiving EOF as well as SIGINT, however I don't know why or how to be sure, or how to stop it doing so.
Any ideas?

Edit: I should mention that it does not seem to matter whether I use Emacs in the terminal emulator or in the GUI.  Usually I prefer using it in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash command  trap  to catch signal if your script is running on Linux.

Comment: I don't follow.  Can you explain better?  You mean in my Python buffer, put the command "trap" before the path to the Python executable? Or you mean execute it in the shell before running emacs?

Comment: Ok I tried changing my Python command to "bash -c 'trap "echo miau" 2; /home/sinclairs/.local/bin/ipython3 -i --simple-prompt'", but this gives the error "Warning (emacs): Python shell prompts cannot be detected."

Comment: I put that command in a file, marked it with executable permissions, and changed my Python interpreter to run it.  Now it runs correctly, but still on the second Ctrl-C, the interpreter quits with the message "Process Python[myscript.py] exited abnormally with code 130"

Comment: It does, however, echo "miau" to the buffer (only on the second Ctrl-C), meaning the trap works but does not succeed in stopping the process from quitting.